# Google map not visible in Fragment Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, maps

i build a Kotlin project with google maps, but the in the map fragment cant load the map, is not visible

[Here is a pic with the fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyESI.png)

And this is my code:

My manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wiboo.luismtz.logisticaapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
            >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeAct" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".OrdenAct"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_orden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

My Activity:

```html
package com.wiboo.luismtz.logisticaapp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_orden.*
import java.util.jar.Manifest

class OrdenAct : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orden)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), 123)

        var list = ArrayList<DetalleSurtido>()
        var os = intent.getStringExtra("orden_surtido")
        tvTitulo.text = "# De orden: " + os
        var url:String = Configuracion.url + "obtenerdetallesurtido.php?orden=" + os

        var rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        var jar = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    for(x in 0 until response.length()) {
                        tvFolioCliente.text = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("orden_cliente")
                        tvProducto.text = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("producto")
                        tvCantidad.text = response.getJSONObject(x).getInt("cantidad").toString()
                        tvUnidad.text =  response.getJSONObject(x).getString("unidad")
                        tvDireccion.text = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("direccion")
                        var esurtido = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("status")

                        if(esurtido == "1"){
                            tvStatus.text = "Estado: Por Surtir"
                        }else if (esurtido == "2"){
                            tvStatus.text = "Estado: Surtido"
                        }
                        var l = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("latitud")
                        var ln = response.getJSONObject(x).getString("longitud")

                        Configuracion.latitud = l.toDouble()
                        Configuracion.longitud = ln.toDouble()
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {  })
        rq.add(jar)



    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == 123){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                var manager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
                var listener = object:LocationListener{
                    override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location) {
                        /*
                        val myloc = LatLng(Configuracion.longitud, Configuracion.latitud)
                        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(myloc).title("El pedido debe ser surtido aqui"))
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myloc, 16f))
                        */
                    }

                    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
                    }

                    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
                    }
                }
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        0, 0f, listener)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(21.097153, -101.643837)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

And my layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fondolistado"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="281dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:context=".OrdenAct" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Folio cliente: "
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFolioCliente"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Producto:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProducto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFolioCliente" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Cantidad:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCantidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvProducto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Unidad:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUnidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCantidad" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Dirección: "
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDireccion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUnidad" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i also include in my google_maps_api.xml the key generated in the developers console and add my SHA-1.

Hope you guys help me.

Thank you